# How to remove BoundingRect from displaying in QGraphicPolygonItem

Tags: qt, user-interface, graphics, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to put a QGraphicsPolygonItem on an ellipse drawn by QPainter in custom QGraphicsItem. My problem is as follows. I have filled the ellipse with grey gredient color and I have filled my rectangle with red color. Now the problem is with the overall display. the QGraphicsPolygonItem shows white background for boundingrect. My question is how I can remove it?!

[image: I would like to remove the white background]

EDIT: My Paint Function

```
QPoint p1(0,0);
QPoint p2(10, 8);

painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
painter->setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
painter->drawEllipse(p2, 100, 100);

painter->setBrush(Qt::gray);
painter->setPen(Qt::black);
painter->drawEllipse(p1, 100, 100);

myPolygon = new QGraphicsPolygonItem(myPolygonPoints, this);
myPolygon->setBrush(Qt::red);
myPolygon->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
myPolygon->show();
```

this is the paint function of my custome QGraphicsItem.

Comment: Can you show your paint function for the custom QGraphicsItem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, creating the QGraphicsPolygonItem in the paint function is really bad; a new item will be created and added to the graphics scene every time the paint function is called and you'll eventually run out of memory!

As you're parenting the item, you're immediately adding it to the scene, so you shouldn't be calling myPolygon->show();

Instantiate a QGraphicsPolygonItem in the derived MyGraphicsItem class...

```
class MyGraphicsItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
    public:
        MyGraphicsItem(QGraphicsItem* parent);

    private:
        QGraphicsPolygonItem* m_pMyPolygon;
}


MyGraphicsItem::MyGraphicsItem(QGraphicsItem* parent)
    : QGraphicsItem(parent)
{

    // assume you've created the points...

    m_pMyPolygon = new MyPolygonItem(myPolygonPoints, this);

    // set the brush and pen for the polygon item
    m_pMyPolygon->setBrush(Qt::transparent);
    m_pMyPolygon->setPen(Qt::red);
}
```

Since the polygon item is parented to the graphicsItem, it will automatically be displayed.

Comment: this didn't work. please see edit. I wrote
    painter->setBrush(Qt::transparent);
after
    painter->drawEllipse(p1, 100, 100);

Comment: thanks for the code. I have one doubt in code in following section.

    painter->setBrush(Qt::transparent);
    painter->setPen(Qt::red);

I used the code in my existing code just to check the brush and pen behaviour. It didn't wipe out white background. It just removed the red FILL. Now it is showing a red polygon line with white background in a white boundingrect.

Comment: I've simplified the answer, let me know how that goes.

Comment: still the same. it is showing a red polygon line with white background in a white boundingrect